# Device Steadily Discharging While Plugged Into AC?

Tags: battery, charging

**Question:** My device (Galaxy Note 2 running the stable CyanogenMod release) is charging extremely slowly and discharges while it's plugged into AC power.

**What happened to cause this and what's happening now:**
My device has been wonderful for over a year. Yesterday it ran down to about 10% and I borrowed a friend's charger. It charged up to 100% surprisingly quickly. I then let it drain down to about 3% before putting it on the charger. I came back to see the OS wasn't booted and it was in the charging screen (provided by the BIOS?). I then left it to charge for several hours and it only got about 10%. Then I was using it and it drained down to 0% while it was plugged in the entire time. The icon showed the charging animation and the Battery Status page (the one with the graph) said that it's charging on AC. Every couple minutes the battery loses another percent even while it's plugged in. While in the BIOS charging screen, I left it to charge for about 6 hours and it ended up with only 34% charge. It would normally be fully charged much earlier than this. Plugging it into my computer via USB seems to also make it discharge. I have tried two different chargers (but the same cable for both chargers and the computer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem by switching cables.

The cable must have gotten a bad connection so the wires dedicated to power could carry less current. You might try bending the cable in a certain direction to get a better connection, but the real solution is to replace the cable.

Answer (score 0):

my phone is also running on cyanogen and unfortunately I have the same problem, this problem may be due to kernel.
here is the solution which I use also.
buy an extra charger of different model say htc  and use this charger till it's charging well, then use the original charger.repeat the procedure if necessary.
it sounds so strange but works luckily.

Comment: I normally use a charger from Motorola. I use that one most of the time, but the one that comes with the Note 2 also doesn't work. I see no difference between chargers.

Comment: I've also experienced this issue on my Galaxy Nexus running CM10.